# {Numpy} Multiply two lists of different size

Tags: python, numpy

I search a solution to multiply a list by a small list, for each sequence, like that :

```
X=[a,b,c]
Y=[d,e]
```

and i want this result (multiply i-1 and i of X by Y, only if i-1 exist).

```
Z=[e*a,d*a+e*b,d*b+e*c]
```

I have some ideas but I am searching something without if/else or adding 0 in X...

A side question is : what is the best ? Usings lists or arrays ? (or other ?)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the logic by which you are constructing `Z`.

Comment: It is not really clear why the first item has a `5*1`, and the middle one `4*1 + 5*2`? Can you specify what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Can describe more generally what you wnat to achieve?

Comment: `4*3` is 12. Where does that output come from?

Comment: Sorry, forgot something. I used an example here because I don't see how to explain what i want to do ! (btw thx for the downvote before I tried to edit...)

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for posting a question and not checking the examples match up and making us try to piece things together

Comment: `4*None` will give you a `TypeError`.

Comment: ok rogan, bye please

Comment: @timgeb Yes, this is for the example, I want to do a[i-1:i]*b for each i of a... "None" is for saying there is no value before a[0] :)

Comment: What I get from all of this is that you don't know what you want to the point of not being able to write a clear specification about the desired output. We cannot help you without that specification.

Comment: No, I dont see the specific word to what I want to do, nothing else. My question is a little bit complicated, but you can consider only that I am not clear, this is more simple :).

Comment: First you add padding tox by (0)+x, then you do [(expr) for i in range(len(x))]. This is not hatd at all.

Comment: Yes, this is a quick and dirty way, and i am searching a better way (without adding 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is called a **"correlation"**.  An easy way to do this is with [`numpy.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html).

As with your example, the endpoints are always tricky with a correlation, and `numpy.correlate` has several options for dealing with them.

Here are a few examples from the docs:

```
>>> np.correlate([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5])
array([ 3.5])

>>> np.correlate([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5], "same")
array([ 2. ,  3.5,  3. ])

>>> np.correlate([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5], "full")
array([ 0.5,  2. ,  3.5,  3. ,  0. ])
```

Comment: @ADumas: No problem. The most difficult searches are when you have an idea in mind and don't know the word for it, and this is especially true for math operations.  You should also check out `numpy.convolve` because often when people think they want `correlate` the actually want `convolve` and visa versa.